# Cicular Combination(Round Robin Conference)

Tags: combinatorics

A round robin conference of prime minister of 40 countries is to be held. The nunber of ways in which they can be seated so that prime minister of Country A neither sits with his counterpart from Country B and  Country C.

With two cases it is easy to solve.
So i tried this(39!-(38!*2*2-37!*2)) but not getting the correct answer

Comment: Your condition is not clear.  Is it just $AB,BA,AC,CA$ that are forbidden or is $BC$, say, also excluded?

Comment: @lulu their is no restriction on BC , A cannot sit next to B AND C.